# What is the difference between createElement(...) and createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', ...)

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I don't understand the difference between createElement(...) and createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', ...)

You can try this following code:

```js
var element1 = document.createElement('form:form');
var element2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'form:form');

console.log(element1.tagName); // FORM:FORM
console.log(element1.localName); // form:form

console.log(element2.tagName); // FORM:FORM
console.log(element2.localName); // form
```

I was thinking it will be the same result but not at all.
Someone know why?

Answer (score 2):

difference between the `createElement` and `createElementNS` is that you can specify the namespace URI in `createElementNS` whereas `createElement` doesn't allow that.

`createElementNS` can be used when you need to create a SVG from the JS. AS SVG needs the namespace URI. You can check the valid namespaces from here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS#Important_Namespace_URIs

If you are creating element in HTML then you may use `createElement` as there is no need of the `namespace` in it but if you are creating HTML in `XHTML` then you need to use `createElementNS` as XHTML needs `namespace` with it.

Comment: And the namespaceURI of an HTML document is `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` so in this context `createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'...` and `createElement(...` should just be the same. I think you missed the question here. (hint: it's about the `:`)

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces in markup are marked by the `namespace:element` syntax (or `namespace:attribute` for that matter)
DOM methods `createElementNS` and `setAttributeNS` do not need this syntax to create elements in the given namespace, but because the markup syntax allows it, they will still recognize it and ignore it.

So that when you stringify your document, you can have

```
<html xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <form:form></form>
</html>
```

Instead of some hard to read

```
<html xmlns:NS0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <NS0:form></form>
</html>
```

`createElement` and `setAttribute` methods however will not recognize this syntax, and will really create an `<xmlns:form:form></form>` element.